npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/admin-resources - Not found in Docker
I'm trying to setup laravel in docker on macOS, while running laravel_node I'm getting following error:
2024-08-10 10:57:02 npm ERR! code E404
2024-08-10 10:57:02 npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/admin-resources - Not found
2024-08-10 10:57:02 npm ERR! 404 
2024-08-10 10:57:02 npm ERR! 404  'admin-resources@0.0.1' is not in the npm registry.
2024-08-10 10:57:02 npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it (or use the name yourself!)
2024-08-10 10:57:02 npm ERR! 404 
2024-08-10 10:57:02 npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
2024-08-10 10:57:02 npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.
2024-08-10 10:57:02 
2024-08-10 10:57:02 npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2024-08-10 10:57:02 npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2024-08-10T09_57_02_898Z-debug.log

package.json file
 {
"private": true,
"name": "purple",
"version": "1.0",
"description": "",
"author": "Themesbrand",
"browserslist": [
    "last 2 version",
    "> 2%"
],
"scripts": {
    "dev": "npm run development",
    "development": "mix",
    "watch": "mix watch",
    "watch-poll": "mix watch -- --watch-options-poll=1000",
    "hot": "mix watch --hot",
    "prod": "npm run production",
    "production": "mix --production"
},
"devDependencies": {
    "axios": "^1.7.3",
    "laravel-mix": "^6.0.3",
    "lodash": "^4.17.19",
    "popper.js": "^1.12",
    "postcss": "^8.3.5",
    "resolve-url-loader": "^5.0.0",
    "rtlcss": "^3.0.0",
    "sass": "^1.15.2",
    "sass-loader": "^8.0.0"
},
"dependencies": {
    "@chenfengyuan/datepicker": "^1.0.9",
    "@curiosityx/bootstrap-session-timeout": "^1.0.0",
    "admin-resources": "git+https://github.com/themesbrand/admin-resources#master",
    "apexcharts": "^3.22.2",
    "bootstrap": "^5.0.1",
    "bootstrap-datepicker": "^1.9.0",
    "bootstrap-editable": "^1.0.1",
    "bootstrap-filestyle2": "^2.1.0",
    "bootstrap-maxlength": "^1.6.0",
    "bootstrap-rating": "0.0.1",
    "bootstrap-timepicker": "^0.5.2",
    "bootstrap-touchspin": "^4.2.5",
    "chance": "^1.1.3",
    "chart.js": "^2.9.4",
    "datatables.net": "^1.10.23",
    "datatables.net-autofill": "^2.3.4",
    "datatables.net-autofill-bs4": "^2.3.4",
    "datatables.net-bs4": "^1.10.20",
    "datatables.net-buttons": "^1.4.2",
    "datatables.net-buttons-bs4": "^1.4.2",
    "datatables.net-keytable": "^2.3.2",
    "datatables.net-keytable-bs4": "^2.3.2",
    "datatables.net-responsive": "^2.2.1",
    "datatables.net-responsive-bs4": "^2.2.1",
    "datatables.net-select": "^1.2.5",
    "datatables.net-select-bs4": "^1.2.5",
    "dragula": "^3.7.2",
    "dropzone": "^5.7.2",
    "echarts": "^5.2.1",
    "flot-charts": "^0.8.3",
    "flot.curvedlines": "^1.1.1",
    "gmaps": "^0.4.24",
    "gulp-rtlcss": "^2.0.0",
    "inputmask": "^4.0.9",
    "ion-rangeslider": "^2.3.0",
    "jquery": "^3.5.1",
    "jquery-countdown": "^2.2.0",
    "jquery-knob": "^1.2.11",
    "jquery-sparkline": "^2.4.0",
    "jquery-steps": "^1.1.0",
    "jquery-validation": "^1.19.3",
    "jquery.easing": "^1.4.1",
    "jquery.flot.tooltip": "^0.9.0",
    "jquery.repeater": "^1.2.1",
    "jszip": "^3.2.2",
    "leaflet": "^1.6.0",
    "magnific-popup": "^1.1.0",
    "masonry-layout": "^4.2.2",
    "metismenu": "^3.0.4",
    "moment": "^2.30.1",
    "node-waves": "^0.7.6",
    "owl.carousel": "^2.3.4",
    "parsleyjs": "^2.9.1",
    "pdfmake": "^0.1.65",
    "select2": "^4.0.10",
    "simplebar": "^4.2.3",
    "spectrum-colorpicker2": "^2.0.5",
    "sweetalert2": "^10.10.4",
    "table-edits": "^0.0.3",
    "tinymce": "^7.3.0",
    "toastr": "^2.1.4",
    "tui-calendar": "^1.12.5",
    "tui-chart": "^3.8.0",
    "tui-date-picker": "^4.0.2",
    "tui-dom": "^3.0.0",
    "tui-time-picker": "^2.0.2",
    "webpack-rtl-plugin": "^1.3.0",
    "wnumb": "^1.2.0"
}

}
Dockerfile
# Use the official PHP 8.2 image with Apache
FROM php:8.2-apache

# Install dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    git \
    curl \
    zip \
    unzip \
    libpng-dev \
    libonig-dev \
    libxml2-dev \
    libzip-dev \
    nodejs \
    npm \
    && docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql mbstring exif pcntl bcmath gd zip

# Install Composer
COPY --from=composer:latest /usr/bin/composer /usr/bin/composer
# Copy custom Apache configuration
COPY docker/apache/000-default.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf

# Enable Apache mod_rewrite
RUN a2enmod rewrite

# Set the working directory
WORKDIR /var/www/html

# Copy the application code to the container
COPY . /var/www/html

# Set up Apache to serve the Laravel application
RUN chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html \
    && chmod -R 755 /var/www/html \
    && chmod -R 775 /var/www/html/storage \
    && chmod -R 775 /var/www/html/bootstrap/cache


# Expose port 80 to the host
EXPOSE 80

# Start Apache in the foreground
CMD ["apache2-foreground"]

If I access https://registry.npmjs.org/admin-resources on browser it shows not found error.
Looks like registry is down or not accessible from my location? Is there any other alternative to this?
How to fix it?

Do you have admin-resources in your package.json file?
And there is no package called this in npm's website: https://www.npmjs.com/package/admin-resources
If you have it on purpose check the spelling of the package.

@thecodingsage I've one package with this name "admin-resources": "git+https://github.com/themesbrand/admin-resources#master",

@thecodingsage Not sure where does "https://registry.npmjs.org/admin-resources" come from? There is no mention of it in package.json, how to check it?

@Raymond can you post complete package.json? since I tried installing this exact dependency and it's working.

@abdurrehman I've updated question with package.json file's content. I've also searched for "admin-resources" in directory and I can't find any other instances.

@Raymond It works for me in local but i check with you later on Docker (i dont have it installed on my new computer) but i dont know you need git or not to use that so try checking and downloading git on your image

@Raymond can you share us your DockerFile?

@thecodingsage I've updated my question with Dockerfile.

@Raymond which command is calling npm i if you didnt call it?

@thecodingsage hello, I don't see npm i command, where is it? No, I don't call it.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

@Raymond were you able to solve it? i tried with given configuration and it’s looking good

@abdurrehman Hello, I couldn't fix this issue and I gave up. Too much hassles.
